# How to center Twitter-Bootstrap tab's items

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to centralize the tab's items and the style to be the same, but I cannot modify my css currently.

I want the tab element to takes 100% width(to be stretched) and the li elements to be at the center of the tab element.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 centered-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Women</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
B.

Comment: I don't think so it is technical, can you please show me the view you want?

Comment: On the link, you could see it - there is a bottom border which shows the with of the tab element. I want the tab items WOMEN and MEN to be at the center
http://postimg.org/image/8x54sphzb/

Comment: The link is showing your result? i am asking the changes you want

Comment: That's what i've added to the standard twitter-bootstrat example:
.centered-tabs { text-align:center; }
.centered-tabs ul.nav-tabs { display:inline-block; }
.centered-tabs li { display:inline; }
.centered-tabs a { float:left; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navbar links are set to `float: left` by default, you need to reset it to `float: none` so that `text-align: center` will have the necessary effect.

Also `display: block` on the list elements make them stack vertically. Set them to `display: inline-block`

```css
.centered-tabs {
  text-align: center;
}
.centered-tabs .nav-tabs > li {
  float: none !important; /* Avoid !important, added for SO snippet priority */
}
.centered-tabs .nav > li {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 centered-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Women</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Men</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```